# Reusing Iterator Variables in Python For Loops

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, enumerate

In Python v2.7.3, can I reuse an iterator variable like this?

```py
for i, name in enumerate(listOfNames):
   ...
```

and then later do:

```py
for i, address in enumerate (addressList):
   ...
```

Comment: Yes you can;  unless you're doing one inside the other, in which case, tread carefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What iterator variable? You aren't re-using anything. You are calling `enumerate` two separate times, so it will produce two separate generators.

The only way you'd get into trouble is if you did something like this

```
>>> listOfNames = ['bob', 'mike', 'steve']
>>> e = enumerate(listOfNames)

>>> for i, name in e:
        print(i)

0
1
2

>>> for i, name in e:
        print(i)

# prints nothing
```

Note that we assigned the return value of the `enumerate` call to a variable `e`. If you try to iterate over that variable twice, you will get nothing the second time. In your case, you will not run into this issue

Comment: 'i' is the iterator variable that you can assign, is it not? Could I not do:

    for ham, name in e?

Comment: The problem is not the variable on the left (`i` or `ham`), it is the variable on the right. When you say `for _ in enumerate(L)` you are making a **new call to enumerate** so you get a new generator back. If you say `e = enumerate(L)` you assign the returned generator into the variable `e`. So if you say `for _ in e:` you use that generator expression up, and cannot iterate through it again.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying. However, I'm not assigning a variable to the enumerate call and both instances are enumerating separate lists. I'm only talking about the 'i'. So, I guess what I am asking is can I use the 'i' for both instances of enumerate?

Comment: Don't worry about the variable `i`, it will correctly take on the new values in your second `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

*>for i, name in enumerate(listOfNames):
...

> for i, address in enumerate (listofAddress):
> ...

okay, about your case ,i  would say ,these are  two different for-loops combined with two different iterators with  a  method of enumerate().they dont really have a combination with eachother.

Here is a specific example and screenshot of your case running on my computer:

Please if you can check this out from the  url:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U1CJ.png

As you can see from the Sreenshot ,for these two cases:
the first one that producing the names of the list and its index which is [i],
and the second one is trying to do the same thing as in the list called listofAddress and finally produces the index and its vlaue of address.

So which you can see is that these are two compeltely diifferent results from two lists even for 'the Variable of the "same name " called i;

But actually they are different from each other,because they are all stand for the index of the value in their own specific Lists, one is the index of the [listofNames] and the other one is index of the [listofAddress], so they are different, right?

Comment: And you can also check the method called enumerate() ,that could be  informative for you in your case.https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/